# equinumerous between a finite and infinite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinite-groups

I need to write a proof that, given A is a finite set and B is an infinite set, show that A is equinumerous to a subset of B. I understand to show this I need to show a bijection.

I can get the injectivity easily. What I don't understand is how A is how to show A surjective to a subset of B. By the definition of surjection that for each y in B there must exists an x in A such that f(x) = y. Can I just state that is MUST be a subset or else it wouldn't be surjective and therefore A would fail to be equinumerious to a subset of B?

Can I even apply those definitions because they involve a function when the question doesn't mention functions at all?

Comment: Your logic can't include "or else [...] A would fail to be equinumerous to a subset of B", because that's exactly what you're trying to prove, and it sounds like you have in mind a contradiction along the lines of "the thing I'm supposed to prove wouldn't be true, which is a contradiction"

Comment: I thought that was the entire point of using a contradiction.

Comment: It is, but the way you seem to be contemplating its structure seems, to me, to be that the contradiction is that "I know this thing is true. If it weren't true, that would contradict the fact that it is."

Comment: When you write, "I can get the injectivity easily", do you mean you know how to construct an injective mapping $f:A \to B$?

Answer (score 0):

*You* will need to define a function from $A$ to $B$ and then show it is a bijection.

I don't know how technical of a proof they are looking for, but it seems trivial to just say that if $A$ is finite (say, $A = \{ a_1, a_2, ..., a_n \}$ for some number $n$), and $B$ is infinite, then obviously there will be a subset $B'$ of $B$ of size $n$, and so you can say $B' = \{ b_1, b_2, ..., b_n \}$. And then you can define $f(a_i) = b_i$ for all $1 \le i \le n$, and show that this $f$ is a bijection.